# How to run docker commands in azure devops build pipelines by not using standard tasks

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-service-principal

I need to run docker commands such as "docker build" and "docker push" in azure devops build pipelines. I know there are tasks available to do these things such as imagebuildingInfo@1 etc. But issue is I need to do this for a new ACR for each pipeline run, and imagebuildingInfo@1 task expects the service connection of type docker registry not azure rm. So I have to create a new service principal of every run of the pipeline which I can't do.

Is there a way to run docker commands in a script in pipeline? I am trying this

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
                #   displayName: Registry Login
                #   name: acrLogin
                #   env:
                #     ADME_SUBSCRIPTION: 'id'
                #     REGISTRY: 'acr name'
                #   inputs:
                #     azureSubscription: 'azure rm service principal'
                #     scriptType: 'bash'
                #     scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
                #     inlineScript: |
                #      az acr login -n ${REGISTRY}
```

But while running this I am getting the error:

```
WARNING: You may want to use 'az acr login -n <acr_name> --expose-token' to get an access token, which does not require Docker to be installed.

ERROR: 2024-03-20 10:22:28.619871 An error occurred: DOCKER_COMMAND_ERROR
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Which means docker deamon is not running on the agent. We have to use a template which might be causing this not to run. Is there a way to run the docker Deamon explicitly in pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

#### Self-hosted agentpool

If you are using a **self-hosted** agentpool where you install the agents yourself, and need to run the `docker` commands directly in other tasks, these are the commands on how I solved that for a self-hosted agentpool and the agent user on the VM:

```bash
# Install Docker (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository)
# Add Docker's official GPG key
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc
# Add the repository to Apt sources
echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME") stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update

# Install the Docker packages
sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin

# Set Docker permissions
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock

# Add agent user to the Docker group
sudo usermod -aG docker <agent-user-here>

# Restart docker
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Installing it in this manner should solve the error:

```
ERROR: 2024-03-20 10:22:28.619871 An error occurred: DOCKER_COMMAND_ERROR
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Once installed you should be i.e. be able to do the following:

```bash
az acr login -n ${REGISTRY}
docker build
docker push
```

I hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I could reproduce the issue with a pipeline running on a Linux self-hosted agent machine, where docker and the pipeline agent service were newly installed.

[image]

This is because the user that the pipeline agent service is configured to run as, is not granted permission to connect to the Docker daemon. When [installing agent service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/linux-agent?view=azure-devops#install) with `sudo ./svc.sh install [username]`,  if `username` parameter is not specified then the username is taken from the $SUDO_USER environment variable which is set by sudo command. This variable is always equal to the name of the user who invoked the `sudo` command.

[image]

Here are my steps to fix the error.

1. Add the user (`Alvin` in my case) to run pipeline agent service in `docker` admin group;

   ```
   sudo usermod -aG docker Alvin
   ```
2. Stop pipeline agent service in the agent physical location directory;

   ```
   sudo ./svc.sh stop
   ```

   [image]
3. Configure agent service with [environment update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/linux-agent?view=azure-devops#service-update-environment-variables) (docker permission assigned);

   ```
   ./env.sh
   ```

   [image]
4. Start the pipeline agent service and `Rerun failed jobs` without changing anything in the pipeline;

   ```
   sudo ./svc.sh start
   ```

   [image]